# Buffering and Caching a video in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, caching, projekktor

I am trying to buffer / cache large video streams whenever the HTML5  tag is present.  The reason I am doing this is to have the ability "scrub" (i.e. move the playhead back-and-forth) the video frame-by-frame without having to request that individual part of the video from the server each time (doing that will cause jumpy frame scrubbing and also negatively impact people viewing over slower connections).  Its worth mentioning that I am attempting ultimately presenting the videos through Projekktor.  So far I have tried:

Using preload but to no success i.e.:

```
$("video").on("load", function() {
   $("video").attr("preload", "auto");
});
```

I have also tried to specify video data with in the source itself, however, for large pages this causes performance issues (brings the Javascript engine to its knees) i.e. something like (projekktor aside):

```
<video><source type="video/mp4"; src="base64,"/></video>
...
...
<script type="text/javascript">
...
var vidData = myLargVideo;
$("video").attr("src", "base64," + myLargeVideo);
...
</script>
```

I have tried to manipulate the client browser using cache directives (i.e. Expires and Cache-Control) to no real effect, Chrome only caches the first 9 or so megabytes at its discretion.

I feel as if I am not on the right track any more but also feel there must be a more elegant approach out there which involves roughly what I am doing.  Any ideas? am I asking the impossible? Thoughts and suggestions would be much appreciated! Thank you!

In the meantime will continue to try out various things and will post here if I find anything noteworthy.

Comment: Safari is also one of my targets.  I don't care too much about Firefox just yet ( it can't play h264 vids :( ).

Comment: No joy on this.  Unfortunately, I have to move on but will probably return to it in the future.